# Cycles render starts black and then renders as white

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

When I go to render my project; the render preview starts off black, and what is rendered is just a solid white. I've let it render until it's finished just to be sure, but it is in fact a blank white image.

I've started a new render so that I can provide an image of the problem:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4v-GkVPDQUQVXZfRWd6TEU3Tzg/view?usp=sharing

Here is my project file from my google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4v-GkVPDQUQaHdtdWU5RGVsa0E/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

You are viewing the rendered image in the Alpha mode, so it's showing you the transparent data. To toggle back to the Color view, select the checker-board icon in the image viewer:

[image]